# Date Picker Works for First Row only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rows

i am using HTML table for displaying set of data. i have a cell for date field (using input type='text'). users can edit the date at run time. but whenever i edit the date, it affects only the first row of the HTML table. can you please any one help me out? 
i created table in server side (ASPX).

the following code i developed in serverside page. (Ex: Sample.aspx.cs)

```
 sbr.Append("<table class ='gstd' style='WIDTH: 98%; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;' id='tblHistory'> <tbody><TR style='POSITION: relative; TOP: 14%; ; TOP: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop - 2)'> ")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr'  style='width:4%;'> Select</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr'  style='width:10%;text-decoration: underline;'> Equipment No</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:8%;text-decoration: underline;'> Repair Company</TD>")
        **sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:8%;text-decoration: underline;'> Date</TD>")**
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:10%;text-decoration: underline;'> Pool</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:8%;text-decoration: underline;'> Local Amount</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:6%;text-decoration: underline;'> CUR</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:8%;text-decoration: underline;'> Original Amount</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:8%;text-decoration: underline;'> Amount in USD</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:4%;text-decoration: underline;'> Country</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:10%;text-decoration: underline;'> Organization</TD>")
        sbr.Append("<TD align=center Class='ghdr' style='width:12%;text-decoration: underline;'> Reason</TD>")
        sbr.Append("</TR>")
        For Each drUser As DataRow In dtContainerHistory.Rows
            sbr.Append("<TR class='gitem'><TD align=left class='gitem'> <input type='checkbox' id='chkSelect' onclick='getRowItem(this)' />")
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("EQPMNT_NO"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("RPR_CMPNY_SHRT_NAM"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD> ")
            **sbr.Append("<input type='text' id='txtRepairedDate' class='datepicker' value=""" & drUser.Item("RPR_CMPLT_DT") & """ style='width:90px;' />")**
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("PL_SHRT_NAM"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=right class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("APPRVL_AMNT"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("CRRNCY_CD"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=right class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("ORGNL_ESTMT_AMNT"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=right class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("AMNT_IN_BS_CRRNCY"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("CNTRY_CD"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("ORGNZTN_SHRT_NAM"))
            sbr.Append("</TD><TD align=left class='gitem'>")
            sbr.Append(drUser.Item("DCSN_RSN_VC"))
            sbr.Append("</TD>")
            sbr.Append("</TR>")
        Next
```

The following code i placed in design page.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("[name^=dtPicker]").datepicker({      
            showOn: 'button',
            dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'http://localhost/testUI/images/calendar.png'
        });
    });
```

Comment: you mean to say that i have to use the code which is given by you in the above instead of the code which i mentioned in the above (The following code i placed in design page.)section.

Comment: i modified the code as per your suggestion.   $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://localhost/localUI//images/calendar.png'
            });
        }); but still the same issue exists

Comment: None of the code in the question has matching `name^=dtPicker` - if it works on first row, then you're doing something that's not included in the question.  You also have a ton of code that clearly isn't relevant to the question.  Please read this, all 3 factors apply here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Sorry, i missed to add in my code. you are correct. i can replace name=dtpicker by id=txtRepairedDate. i tried with name,id and class. but nothing is help. can you please tell me what do you are expecting relevant to my question. the code whatever i mentioned in the above is i used in my page.

Comment: Put simply, each `id` should be unique on the page.  From wading through the irrelevant parts of your code, it looks like *every* row has `id=txtRepairedDate`, which is not valid HTML and, from your *comment* if you use that as a selector, you'll get the first.   Basically, use `$(".datepicker")` in your setup.  Remove the irrelevant code and put the actual code you use and you'll likely get a decent answer.

Comment: i understand your point. but i have a question in this case. i replace asp grid by HTML table. so i bind the HTML TABLE when the page is loading. this is what my code. i don't know how to created unique id here. even i create unique id how i can related unique ID with jquery function. please help to get through this problem

Comment: The answer is: don't use the `id` in the selector.  (as you said you have in your real code, but do not in the question code - the question should be updated).

Comment: From where you are putting data in table? hardcoded or from database?

Comment: i use to fill the data from database. i am very happy to say that i got an output just now. i use the "type" selector instead of "id". it works. thanks for your valuable effort for me to get through this issue. your advise is always valuable one. thanking you once again.

Answer (score 0):

after a bundle of discussions here, i found the solution. if you have same issue, please replace your "id"or"name"or"class" by "type" as below:

**Old Code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             **$("[name^=dtPicker]").datepicker({**      
                showOn: 'button',
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://localhost/localUI//images/calendar.png'
            });
        });
```

**New Code (Solution):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            **$("[type$=text]").datepicker({**
                showOn: 'button',
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://localhost/localUI//images/calendar.png'
            });
        });
```